# Play! Framework support for Java 8 Optional

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, java-8

I've got a Play! 2 routes file and controller that looks something like this:

`GET /books BooksController.getBooks(author: play.libs.F.Option[String])`

```
public class BooksController extends Controller {

  public static Result getBooks(play.libs.F.Option<String> author) {
    ...
  }    
}
```

I would like to refactor it to use Java 8's `Optional`, but this causes a compilation error:

`GET /books BooksController.getBooks(author: java.util.Optional[String])`

```
public class BooksController extends Controller {

  public static Result getBooks(java.util.Optional<String> author) {
    ...
  }    
}
```

I've tried creating a custom [QueryStringBindable](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/api/java/play/mvc/QueryStringBindable.html), but that forces me to type the controller's parameters as the bindable's type, not `Optional`. Any other ways of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible right now. There is an [github issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4692) to replace `F.Option` with `java.util.Optional`. It will be delivered in `Playframework 2.5.0`.